# ¿Definicion métodos estáticos? JAVA

Tags: java

Tengo un problema definiendo un metodo estático en una clase, a ver si pueden ayudarme:

```js
public boolean checkcmd(String in, String cmd, String ... arg)
{
 ...
 check.a(); // esta linea
 ...
}
class check
{
 static void a()
 {
  ...
 }
}
```

El error que obtengo es "Unreachable code", en la linea marcada.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Agrega el código que tienes alrededor de `Check.a()`.

Comment: un método estático sólo puede ser llamado por otros métodos estáticos o por herencia de clases hijas, por eso el código en ese punto es "inalcanzable", teorícamente hablando. Falta ver tu código para saber el porqué exacto.

Comment: @L.Ronquillo "un método estático sólo puede ser llamado por otros métodos estáticos o por herencia de clases hijas" totalmente equivocado. Ejemplo: `class X { static void imprimir(String s) { System.out.println(s); } void saludar(String nombre) { imprimir("Hola " + nombre); } }`

Comment: Necesitamos ver el código que ejecutas para detectar el caso puntual. Que invoques a un método estático no se asocia al problema en cuestión.

Comment: @LuiggiMendozaJ ¿lo que recordaba de la universidad está mal entonces? jaja, borraré el comentario en cuestión para no confundir al OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El compilador detecta que el método, en un punto, va a terminar de alguna manera o que no hay forma de continuar la ejecución, así que código escrito luego de ese punto de fin **no se va a ejecutar**. Esto genera el "Unreachable code".

Ejemplos:

1. Lanzar una excepción deliberadamente:

   ```
   public void x() {
       throw new UnsupportedOperationException("no ejecutar");
       //el código después de este throws no se puede ejecutar
       System.out.println("x");
   }
   ```
2. Retornar un valor, o simplemente retornar si es un método `void`:

   ```
   public void x() {
       return;
       //el código después de este return no se puede ejecutar
       System.out.println("x");
   }
   ```
3. Tener un bucle infinita:

   ```
   public void x() {
       while (true) {
           /* funcionalidad */
       }
       //el código después de un bucle infinito
       System.out.println("x");
   }
   ```

Hay casos donde resulta un poco más difícil de detectar (pero no imposible). Ejemplo:

```
public int duplicar(int a) {
    if (a >= 0) {
        return a * 2;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("solo para numeros positivos");
    }
    //la sentencia de abajo genera Unreachable code
    System.out.println("Código inalcanzable!");
}
```

Dicho esto, necesitamos tu código completo para detectar el unreachable code.

Que el método invocado dentro de tu método de instancia sea un método estático **no está asociado al problema**.